# Python UDF with Row input

Tags: apache-flink

I need to dynamically register python functions provided during job initialization(runtime/job java). I'm using the `create temporary system function`..`language python` to do it.
However, I need the UDFs to receive the entire row, not column by column.

Option 1(doesn't meet requirements):

```
@udrf(result_type=DataTypes.BOOLEAN())
def foofn(foo, bar, baz) -> bool:
    return True
```

called as

```
env.from("sometable").filter(call("foofn", $("*")));
```

Option 2(row without names):
With this option you get a row but names are replaced with f0, f1,...

```
@udrf(result_type=DataTypes.BOOLEAN())
def foofn(row: Row) -> bool:
    return True
```

called as

```
env.from("sometable").filter(call("foofn", $("*")));
```

Option 3(new decorate):
This is the one I think it should be an enhancement
New decorator(same(copu) as udf but changes the take_row_as_input)

```
def _create_udrf(f, input_types, result_type, func_type, deterministic, name):
    udrf = UserDefinedScalarFunctionWrapper(f, input_types, result_type, func_type, deterministic, name)
    udrf._set_takes_row_as_input()
    
    return udrf


def udrf(f: Union[Callable, ScalarFunction, Type] = None, input_types: Union[List[DataType], DataType, str, List[str]] = None, result_type: Union[DataType, str] = None, deterministic: bool = None, name: str = None, func_type: str = "general", udf_type: str = None) -> Union[UserDefinedScalarFunctionWrapper, Callable]:

    if func_type not in ('general', 'pandas'):
        raise ValueError("The func_type must be one of 'general, pandas', got %s."
                                         % func_type)

    # decorator
    if f is None:
        return functools.partial(_create_udrf, input_types=input_types, result_type=result_type, func_type=func_type, deterministic=deterministic, name=name)
    else:
        return _create_udrf(f, input_types, result_type, func_type, deterministic, name)
```

then

```
@udrf(result_type=DataTypes.BOOLEAN())
def foofn(row: Row) -> bool:
    return True
```

called as

```
env.from("sometable").filter(call("foofn", $("*")));
```

With option I get a row with the proper names.
Is there any other option I'm missing?